# How to generate non-equal random numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I am trying to find 10 random numbers between 100 and 1000 and if any of the numbers are equal then I need to have the computer choose a different random number. Does anyone know how to do this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       var numbers=[];
       var max=110;
       var min=100;
       numbers [1]= Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
       numbers [2]= Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
       numbers [3]= Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
       numbers [4]= Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
       numbers [5]= Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
       numbers [6]= Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
       numbers [7]= Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
       numbers [8]= Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
       numbers [9]= Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
       numbers [10]= Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;


    do (numbers[2]);

           while (numbers[1]===numbers[2]);
    do (numbers[3]);

           while (numbers[1] == numbers[3])     
           (numbers[2] == numbers[3]);


       for (i in numbers){
           document.writeln("<br>"+numbers[i]);
       }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like

```
<script>
    var foo = {}

    while (Object.keys(foo).length < 10) {
        foo[Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min] = true;
    }

    var numbers = Object.keys(foo);
</script>
```

Comment: This uses an object to simulate a set, see http://www.javascriptexamples.org/2011/01/17/how-to-implement-a-set-in-javascript/

Answer (score 2):

```
var numbers = [];
var max = 1000;
var min = 100;

while (numbers.length < 10) {
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min
  if(numbers.indexOf(num)!= -1){
    numbers.push(num)
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that it is almost impossible to create a (very) well distributed random numbers using floats. It's not that the answer is wrong, but don't start a lottery using this. Also note that `Math.random()` is not likely to be cryptographically secure.

Comment: Eh, shouldn't max be 1000?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Yep, overlooked that. Fixed now.

Comment: Note that I've voted to reopen the question. Maybe it's got a dupe, I don't know, but now the title has been altered the question should be clear. Maybe you want to do the same.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Not enough rep:(

Comment: Oops, sorry, I don't know the rep requirements from the top of my head :P

Comment: Voting to close/reopen is 3000, since I recently got it :)

Answer (score 1):

use this code:

```
var numbers = [];
var max = 110;
var min = 100;

while (numbers.length != 10) {
    var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

    var exists = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if (number == numbers[i])
            exists = true;
    }

    if (!exists)
        numbers.push(number);
}

console.log(numbers);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shiralizadeh/g1rxuskb/)

Answer (score 1):

You can keep checking for repeated numbers since in your case they do not appear often, but I would implement a **random seed** in this case since you would not need to check for duplicates at all.

All you got to do is replace `Math.random` with your custom random function and remove all those unnecessary while loops.
Example:

```js
var seed = Math.random(); 
var random = function(){
  return parseFloat('0.'+Math.sin(++seed).toString().substr(6));
};  
var r = [];
for(var i=0; i < 10; i++){
  r[i] = random();
}
document.body.textContent = r.join(' ');
```

Read more about [random seeds](http://www.grasshopper3d.com/forum/topics/what-are-random-seed-values)

Comment: This is the first time I see Math.sin being used for random number generation. How good is it vs Math.random?

Comment: It is actually a trick ... I don't know exactly how the [distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution) behaves, but in practice it works like a charm ;D !!! If you try to analyse it geometrically, it seems like a pretty linear distribution.